# How to get xmlaccess port number on AIX/UNIX box?

Tags: websphere

I am trying to look for xmlaccess port number along with the configuration location on AIX / UNIX box, where WebSphere Portal 6.0 is installed, can you help with a script that I can use as i have multiple boxes and instance to search on?

Attempted the following without success:
I have tried to use find command but there are too many results and warnings as i do not have admin privileges i keep getting tons of results like the ones shown below,

find: 0652-081 cannot change directory to :
  : The file access permissions do not allow the specified action.

This is very tedious and time consuming to follow thorough, when you have scores of warnings coming through.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following and let me know how you get along,

$ grep -e "XmlAccessPort=" `find / -name wpconfig.properties 2>/dev/null`

Hint : You can fine tune the above find script if you know the location of the Portal Installation.

Sample output:
/WebSphere/PortalServer/config/wpconfig.properties:XmlAccessPort=60644

Answer (score 0):

In a typical installation it should be on the same port that Portal runs on. For Portal 7, that typically has been 10039. I haven't worked with verion 6 to add much more than that though.